# Click link to ask save changes and refresh on another page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two pages: main page and child page. on the main page, I have a link will direct user to the child page. And in the main page, there's a listener to check if child window closed, it will refresh main page automatically.

in the main page, the link is:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlchild" runat="server" NavigateUrl="javascript:void(openchild('../test/child','child'));">child page</asp:HyperLink>
```

and below is the function for openchild:

var childWindow;
var timer;

```
    function openchild(vurl) {
        childWindow = window.open(vurl, 'child');
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = setInterval(checkChild, 1000);
    }

    function checkChild() {
        if (childWindow.closed) {
            childWindow = null;
            clearInterval(timer);
            __doPostBack('hdPB_Refreshpage', '');
        }
    }
```

Now, I want to add a function: whenever I click the child link from main page, checking whether the child page is opened. if yes, then ask user whether save changes on child page before refresh the child page. If user click yes, then it will trigger the save changes function on child, otherwise just refresh the child page to open.

below is the button on child page for saving changes:

```
<button type="submit" id="subSave" name="Save" value="Save" class="btn btn-outline-dark">
<i class="far fa-save"></i> Save
</button>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the 'correct' way to do things, but you can have cross-page communication by localStorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event

Comment: You might be able to do something similar via webworkers, but I'm not as sure about that

Comment: So the idea would be to listen for localStorage changes on the child page, and then when you want to trigger a save from the parent page, you change some localStorage value, `localStorage.saveChild = new Date();` or something

Answer (score 0):

You should use cross window communications that js expose, like post messages, more you can read [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Just add event listener on the child window with the name of message that you will sent, and from parent window send that message.

```
var childWindow = window.open(/* details */);

childWindow.postMessage("hello world", "http://example.com");

window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
    if (event.origin !== "http://example.com")
    return;

    // event.source is childWindow
    // event.data
}, false);
```

Comment: so for that way, I could send a message from parent to child, but how I could trigger the save changes on child page itself. Actually I dont need any information from parent to child, but I just need child itself to be saved if user click yes to save changes.

Comment: if user click yes on parent window just send a message to child and on child window trigger save changes function on message received

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think your answer is better for if I need data post also from parent to child. Finally I just from parent to call a function in child.

Comment: You welcome) and if it helped you please accept that answer)

Answer (score 0):

Just a update for my solution. So finally I just call the function from child window.
In the main page:

```
   var childWindow;
var timer;
function openchild(vurl) {
//check if the child window is existing, then popup for asking whether save changes
 if (childWindow != null) {
                if (confirm('Do you want to save changes before proceeding?')) {
                    //save changes on that page
                    childWindow.ProcessParentSaveChanges();
                    childWindow.focus();
                    return;
                }
            }

        childWindow = window.open(vurl, 'child');
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = setInterval(checkChild, 1000);
    }

    function checkChild() {
        if (childWindow.closed) {
            childWindow = null;
            clearInterval(timer);
            __doPostBack('hdPB_Refreshpage', '');
        }
    }
```

in child page:

```
function ProcessParentSaveChanges() {
            var btn = document.getElementById("subSave");
            btn.form.submit();
        }
```